# Closing Connections for FlowPlayer in Chrome "Caution provisional headers are shown" Error

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, flowplayer

While playing 6-7 videos in flowplayer I get the warning `Caution provisional headers are shown`  On Chrome.

On Checking `net-internals` the connection is waiting for sockets

```
t= 18186 [st=     0] +REQUEST_ALIVE  [dt=444781]
                      --> has_upload = false
                      --> is_pending = true
                      --> load_flags = 142737664 (ENABLE_LOAD_TIMING | MAYBE_USER_GESTURE | REPORT_RAW_HEADERS | VERIFY_EV_CERT)
                      --> load_state = 2 (WAITING_FOR_AVAILABLE_SOCKET)
                      --> method = "GET"
                      --> status = "IO_PENDING"
                      --> url = "<url>"
t=462966 [st=444780]    CANCELLED
t=462966 [st=444780]   -HTTP_STREAM_REQUEST
t=462967 [st=444781]   -URL_REQUEST_START_JOB
                        --> net_error = -3 (ERR_ABORTED)
t=462967 [st=444781]    URL_REQUEST_DELEGATE  [dt=0]
t=462967 [st=444781] -REQUEST_ALIVE
```

Is there any way to close existing connections in flowplayer HTML version?

On flowplayer close

```
var api = flowplayer();
api = $(".flowplayer:first").data("flowplayer");
api.unbind();
api.unload();
```

Any way to force close the connections?

Comment: I have the same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25975943/php-serve-mp4-chrome-provisional-headers-are-shown-request-is-not-finished-ye , did you solve it by any chance?

Comment: Nope, Seem like browsers limit concurrent connections to each server. There is an open issue regarding this https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=85323. Currently im using workaround by refreshing and restoring page to clear sockets

Comment: Thanks, can you give me more details about your workaround? I can't even reload my page... the only way to make it work again in my case is to close the current tab and enter the site again...

Comment: Keep track of total number of open socket connections, when maximum is reached, save current session to LocalStorage , then refresh page and restore session from LocalStorage. You can get a list of max allowed connections for each browsers here http://www.coderanch.com/t/631345/blogs/Maximum-concurrent-connection-domain-browsers

Comment: I plan to use wildcard to route all of my subdomains to my main domain and load up videos using subdomains... connection limit should have no effect on subdomain right?